# How do i rebind the listview datasource from jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, listview, telerik

I have a listview that needs to be updated after a comment is added. The submission is handled through jquery, and I'll like to force a refresh after the comment is successfully submitted. Animation would be nice, i was hoping that there is a simple solution. i tried calling a page method to force the rebind but it having to be static has totally lost me as I cannot access the control directly. any help? tia

Comment: Hi, did either of our answers help you?  If not, let me know how I can help.

Answer (score 1):

Since the listview is a server side control, it will only be possible to rebind though a postback.  One way I've done this in the past is to put a hidden "refresh" button on the page

```
<asp:button runat="server" id="btnRefresh" onclick="ReBindListView" style="display:none;" />
```

And then use javascript to cause the postback

```
function refresh() {
      __doPostBack('<%= btnRefresh.ClientID %>', '');
 }
```

On the server side of the btnRefresh click you can then rebind your listview

Comment: No; you can rebind it using JavaScript.

Comment: @msigman the javascript function "refresh" is actually causing a postback and calling the server side RebindListView procedure.

Comment: Your solution is clever!  On the PostBack subject point I'm not actually sure.  Is it doing a .NET PostBack or is it doing a jQuery AJAX call to the server to get the data?  You are probably right it does a PostBack internally.  But at the very least using the predefined JavaScript `rebind()` method is a little simpler because it doesn't require creating the hidden button.

Comment: ah, I missed that this was a telerik question. My solution was for the asp ListView.

Answer (score 0):

You can rebind your RadListView anytime necessary to update it with the new comments.  Here's an example:

```
<telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="RadCodeBlock1" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function RefreshRadListView() {
            var listView = $find("<%= RadListView1.ClientID %>");
            listView.rebind();
        } 
    </script>
</telerik:RadCodeBlock>
```

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/listview-rebind.html